# Nested for_each loops causing unexpected increase in size of a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++17, stdvector

I have the following piece of code that I am using to convert a 2D array of doubles to a 1D vector. The arrays are allocated using std::vector and a nested for_each loop is used to transfer the contents of the 2D array to the 1D array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#define UNUSED(expr) (void)(expr)

using usll = __uint64_t;

void print1d(std::vector<double> vv);
void matToVect1d(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& v2d, std::vector<double>& v1d);
void matToVect1dEx(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& v2d, std::vector<double>& v1d);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    const usll DIM0 {10};
    const usll DIM1 {8};

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> data2d(DIM0, std::vector<double>(DIM1));
    std::vector<double> data1d(DIM0 * DIM1);
    double temp = 0.0;

    for (usll i{}; i<DIM0; ++i)
    {
        for (usll j{}; j<DIM1; ++j)
        {
            data2d[i][j] = temp++;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        matToVect1d(data2d, data1d);
        std::cout << "2D array data2d as a 1D vector is:" << std::endl;
        print1d(data1d);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Press enter to continue";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void print1d(std::vector<double> vv)
{
    for (size_t i{}; i<vv.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vv[i] << "  ";

        if ((i+1)%10 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void matToVect1d(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& v2d, std::vector<double>& v1d)
{
    if (v1d.size() != v2d.size()*v2d[0].size())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("An exception was caught. The sizes of the input arrays must match.");
    }

    for_each(v2d.cbegin(), v2d.cend(), [&v1d](const std::vector<double> vec)
    {
        for_each(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [&v1d](const double& dValue)
        {
            v1d.emplace_back(dValue);
        });
    });

}

void matToVect1dEx(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& v2d, std::vector<double>& v1d)
{
    usll index{};

    if (v1d.size() != v2d.size()*v2d[0].size())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("An exception was caught. The sizes of the input arrays must match.");
    }

    for (usll i=0; i<v2d.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (usll j=0; j<v2d[0].size(); ++j)
        {
            index = j + i*v2d[0].size();
            v1d[index] = v2d[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Each time I run the code, the output is:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39 
40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49 
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59 
60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69 
70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
```

Which is twice as large as the original 1D array. What? Where did the zeros come from? What caused the vector size to grow from 80 to 160? In contrast, when I change the for_each loop to regular for loops, I get the correct output:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39 
40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49 
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59 
60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69 
70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
```

I suspect the anomaly is due to the use of the for_each algorithm, yet Meyer (2018) in his book *Effective C++ Digital Collection: 140 Ways to Improve Your Programming* says "the algorithm call is preferable." He says, and I quote: *"From an efficiency perspective, algorithms can beat explicit loops in three ways, two majors, one minor. The minor way involves the elimination of
redundant computations."*

In my actual use case, the method `matToVect1d()` is called a few `1000` times and the total number of elements per array is `240 x 200`.

My final question is whether it makes sense to implement the loop using the for_each algorithm? Answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Tangent] You can change `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` to `int main()` so you don't have to use `UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);
`.  It's also less typing so it's a win-win

Comment: [Another tangent] When you wrote `for_each(v2d.cbegin(), v2d.cend(), [&v1d](const std::vector<double> vec)`, you probably meant `for_each(v2d.cbegin(), v2d.cend(), [&v1d](const std::vector<double>& vec)`

Comment: I think you should use C++11 for (each) instead if for_each. Your code is hard to read because it uses a lot of braces initializers instead of assignments. I suggest you to use a debugger to find out where your error resides.

Comment: @AndyG Noted, with thanks. Added the const to prevent the unnecessary copying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because of the line

```
std::vector<double> data1d(DIM0 * DIM1);
```

where the `data1d` you create a *vector of `double`s* and initialize it with `0.0` s in `DIM0` x `DIM0` in size.
Therefore, later in `std::for_each` case, when you `std::vector::emplace_back`, you insert the elements after this. Hence, you see `DIM0` x `DIM0` `0` s and later the element that you inserted.

You need instead [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) for the desired behaviour

```
std::vector<double> data1d;
data1d.reserve(DIM0 * DIM1);  // for unwated reallocations
```

---

> I suspect the anomaly is due to the use of the for_each algorithm[...]

**No**, for the reason(i.e. mistake) mentioned above.

---

> My final question is whether it makes sense to implement the loop
>   using the `std::for_each` algorithm?

There is nothing wrong with `std::for_each` approach, other than you copy the `std::vector<double>` in the first lambdas parameter list and (maybe) less readable.

```
std::for_each(v2d.cbegin(), v2d.cend(), [&v1d](std::vector<double> const& vec)
                                               //                  ^^^^^^ --> prefer const-ref
{
    for_each(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [&v1d](const double dValue)
    {
        v1d.emplace_back(dValue);
    });
});
```

than the [range - `for-loop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) approach shown below

```
std::vector<double> data1d;
data1d.reserve(DIM0 * DIM1);  // for unwated reallocations

// ... later in the function

for (const std::vector<double>& vector : v2d)
    for (const double element : vector)
        v1d.emplace_back(element);
```

Comment: I think I see the issue now, just like other answers have pointed out. Nevertheless, it's always good to come back to stack overflow and get oneself set straight. I missed that little detail of emplace_back adding to the end of the vector. Since this answer provides more details, I am going to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: If I still want to initialise the vector before using it, is there a way one can move the pointer back to the beginning before calling emplace_back()?

Comment: @unbound37 No, [`emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) appends the new elements to the end of the container. For specifying the position/ index where you want to insert the new elements, you can use either of the following members: [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), [`std::vector::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) or [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector<double> data1d(DIM0 * DIM1);` <- this line of code doesn't "reserve". It fills the vector with `DIM0 * DIM1` default initialised doubles. 
This is the constructor you are using. 
`vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`

Check this for more reference:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Change it to this:

```cpp
std::vector<double> data1d();
data1d.reserve(DIM0 * DIM1);
```

Comment: Liked the link. I think I missed that little detail of emplace_back appending new items to the vector